# On the convergence of the ratio of order statistics of gaps induced by $n$ uniform points on $[0,1].$

Tags: pr.probability

In an MO question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/339164/on-the-largest-and-smallest-spacings-for-the-uniform-distribution) @IosifPinelis shows that the ratio of expectations $\mathbb{E}(A)/\mathbb{E}(B)$ of the largest (say $A$) and smallest (say $B$) gap resulting from $n$ uniform random variables on $(0,1]$ tends to infinity as $n\rightarrow \infty.$

In an earlier question, linked in the above question, he also showed that $\mathbb{E}(A/B)$ equals to infinity for all $n>2.$

I have a related question (thanks @YuvalPeres for your comments):

*Let $G_{(1)}$ be the smallest, $G_{(2)}$ be the second smallest, etc. and let $G_{(n)}$ be the largest gap.*

*What is the fastest growing sequence $\ell(n)$ such that 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\mathbb{E} G_{(\ell(n))}}{\mathbb{E} G_{(1)}}<\infty?$$*

**Edit:** Simulations seem to confirm the proof by @MattF. that $\ell(n)=2$ yields $7/3.$

Comment: These are random variables- did you want to take expectations or otherwise mention which notion of limit you are asking about?.

Comment: Also note that in the earlier question, @IosifPinelis showed that ratio $E(A/B)$ equals infinity for all $n>2$, not just tends to infinity.

Comment: @kodlu : I guess you wanted something else, because the probability under the limit sign is just $1$.

Comment: Perhaps any unbounded $\ell(n)$ violates this condition.

Comment: @MattF. interesting, I was thinking maybe $\ell(n)=\log(n)$ or an iterated log might not...

Comment: Have you simulated these quantities for $\ell(n)=\log_2(n)$ and $n=2,4,8,16$?

Comment: I think Matt's intuition about unbounded $\ell(n)$ is right. Moreover, because for the density of the standard exponential distribution we have $e^{-x}\sim1$ as $x\downarrow0$, I think $EG_{(\ell(n))}/EG_{(1)}\sim\ell(n)$ if $1\le\ell(n)=o(n)$. (Think of a histogram for a sample from the exponential distribution. Also, recall that, as noted in the linked answer, the gaps $G_i$ are proportional to iid random variables $H_i$ each having the exponential distribution.) Also, I think you meant $EG_{(\ell(n))}$  in place of $EG_{\ell(n)}$.

Comment: In the case $n=4$, we can use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2631988/find-joint-distribution-of-minimum-and-maximum-of-iid-random-variables to get an exact result of $EG_2/EG_1=(7/48)/(1/16)=7/3$, by EG1 = Integrate[Min[1 - ma, (1 - u) (ma - mi), u (ma - mi), mi] 12 (ma - mi)^2, {ma, 0, 1}, {mi, 0, ma}, {u, 0, 1}]; EG2 = Integrate[Min[ma - mi, u ma + (1 - u) mi, (1 - u) ma + u mi, 1 - (ma - mi), 1 - (u ma + (1 - u) mi), 1 - ((1 - u) ma + u mi)] 12 (ma - mi)^2, {ma, 0, 1}, {mi, 0, ma}, {u, 0, 1}] - EG1

Comment: @MattF. : The value $7/3$ for $EG_{(2)}/EG_{(1)}$ looks plausible to me: it is somewhat close to the limit $2$ (which latter is what my conjecture predicts for $n\to\infty$) but also a bit greater than $2$ (which reflects the fact that the exponential density is decreasing on $(0,\infty)$ and hence the sample values tend to be sparser farther away from $0$).

Comment: My simulations for $n=4$ show roughly 2.26 which is consistent with 7/3. @IosifPinelis, do you have a proof idea for your conjecture?

Comment: Also, for completeness, simulations show 2.12 for n=8 and 2.095 for n=16.

Comment: It might help to use the notation $X_{(a:n)}$ for the $a$th smallest of $n$. I think you mean that you evaluated $E[X_{(3:8)}]/E[X_{(1:8)}]$ and $E[X_{(4:16)}]/E[X_{(1:16)}]$.

Comment: @MattF. thanks, I've also fixed an error and the corrected data is below in the next comment.

Comment: We have: E[X{( 2 : 4 )/E[X{(1: 4 )]= 2.4889, E[X{( 3 : 8 )/E[X{(1: 8 )]= 3.5700, and E[X{( 4 : 16 )/E[X{(1: 16 )]= 4.4821

Comment: @kodlu: are u from Turkey?

Comment: @kodlu : Yes, now there is a proof of the conjecture, and even a simple exact expression for $EG_{n-1:i}$. Please see my answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [now shown](https://works.bepress.com/iosif-pinelis/17/) that for $i=1,\dots,n-1$
\begin{equation}\label{eq:EG}
 E G_{n-1:i}=\frac{H_{n-1}-H_{n-1-i}}{n+1}, 
\end{equation}
where $G_{n-1:i}$ is the $i$th smallest value among the gaps $G_1,\dots,G_{n-1}$ defined in the [linked post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/339164/on-the-largest-and-smallest-spacings-for-the-uniform-distribution) and 
\begin{equation*}
 H_k:=1+\frac12+\dots+\frac1k 
\end{equation*}
is the $k$th harmonic number, with $H_0:=0$.

In particular, this confirms my conjecture made in an above comment that 
$$r_{n-1:i}:=\frac{E G_{n-1:i}}{E G_{n-1:1}}\sim i
$$
if $1\le i=o(n)$.

It also follows that $r_{4-1:2}=5/2$ and $r_{5-1:2}=7/3$. This seems to differ a bit from Matt's results, perhaps because Matt used notations differing from those in the [linked post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/339164/on-the-largest-and-smallest-spacings-for-the-uniform-distribution).